# Is it possible to use a .Net payload with metasploit?

Tags: exploit, .net, metasploit

I'm not exactly sure how metasploit works when exploiting a target machine, and it has been a while since of played with it, so forgive me.

Instead of using meterpreter as a payload in metasploit, could I write my own .Net based executable that would be dropped on a system after exploitation? Assuming the victim had .Net on their machine of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few different ways.

First, if your exploit is an EXE-dropping exploit (like psexec), you can set the [`EXE::Custom` advanced option](https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2011/08/custom-payloads-in-metasploit-4/).

Otherwise you can use one of the payloads that allows you to upload ([`windows/upexec/*`](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/payload/windows/upexec/reverse_tcp)) or download ([`windows/download_exec`](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/payload/windows/download_exec)) a custom executable.

Comment: hi can we use this method for custom apk payload as well ?